# Lifetime of Lucene.net objects?

Tags: lucene.net

I'm developing an "indexing service" (as part of a WPF application) that will run on a background thread, and use a FileSystemWatcher to monitor some files. When the file contents change I want to extract some information and update a Lucene index. Occasionally the user may wish to perform a search against the index.

Should I create an index reader every time the user performs a search? And a writer every time the indexes are updated? Or is it okay for my indexing service class (which is a singleton) to have singleton reader and writer instances (plus a singleton FSDirectory, that they both have a dependency on)?

If I was to use singleton instances, do I need to worry about closing/disposing them? If so, should my indexing service implement `IDisposable`, and do the cleanup in `Dispose()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Lucene's `InderWriter` and `IndexReader` instances are thread-safe: you should not have any issues reusing them as singletons. Initializing a new instance of either is extremely expensive (there was a noticeable improvement when a similar design choice was made for both writing and searching, close to 60% for the latter).

For the `IndexWriter` simply keep a private instance that you expose via the `IndexingService`. For the `IndexReader` you need a different approach that can handle changes to the index. Based on the source, you can do,

```
public class IndexingService

   ...

   public IndexReader GetReader()
   {
       var reopenedReader = this.reader.Reopen(openReadOnly: true);
       if (reopenedReader != this.reader) 
       {
           this.reader.Dispose(); 
           return this.reader = reopenedReader;
       }

       return this.reader;
   }
```

The call to `this.reader.Reopen` will first check whether the reader is current (if no changes have occurred since it was opened), and if so, it will simply return itself. If there have been changes, then the reader will load only the segments that have changed, which is usually a faster operation than loading all segments. You also need to synchronize access to the reader if you are expecting multiple-thread access.

One last thing: you definitely need to dispose of both resources, writer and reader (using the `Dispose()` method), in your case when the application shuts down. Failure to do so can possibly corrupt the index.

Answer (score 0):

It's not optimal to create a writer each time so you are better waiting for a period and writing all changes.  You could push the changes when a user performs a search as well it really depends on how complex your index writing is.

When you commit the changes to the index you need to create a new index reader as it won't pick up the changes otherwise.  So I would but recreation of the index reader into your indexing routine.  But don't recreate the reader unless you have update the index as this will slow your app down.